# Exponential function meaning in physics

Tags: mathematics

I still can not explain why summation of $exp (iy)$ is equal to zero? why the summation of adding vector is equal to zero?

Answer (score 1):

Summing or integrating over a set closed under $y\mapsto\pi+y$ gives $0$, because this mapping multiplies $e^{iy}$ by $-1$.